# Using the twitter bootstrap scroll spy

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, scrollspy

I've been trying and trying to get the scroll spy to work on my bootstrap site, but I'm unable to get it to work. The problem I'm having is, scrolling has no effect, wherever I scroll to. You can see what I'm doing [here](http://www.virika.netii.net).

I've performed all the steps required i.e. below is the body tag

```
  <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#top-fixed-nav">
```

and nav is also there:

```
            <ul class="nav" id="top-fixed-nav">
              <li>
                <a href="#home">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="">
                <a href="#about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="">
                <a href="#howto">How to Use?</a>
              </li>
              <li class="">
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
```

Have called the scrollspy as well.

```
$('#top-fixed-nav').scrollspy();
```

Can anyone please have a look and please point out what I'm overlooking or doing wrong here.

Comment: Try `$('body').scrollspy();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Docs](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#scrollspy) say:

> To easily add scrollspy behavior to your topbar navigation, **add
>   `data-spy="scroll"` to the element you want to spy on** ( most typically
>   this would be the `<body>`). Then add the`data-target` attribute with the
>   ID or class of the parent element of any Bootstrap `.nav` component.

The code you posted wasn't working because you were spying on `#top-fixed-nav` (scroll events).

Answer (score 1):

try this: [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/quanganh/Tj3ha/6)

if Scrollspy highlight final element, you can add

> height: 100%

to html and body tag